# ion-label not correctly aligned with its group

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

[bug] label in `div` tag jump to another group of items at its top.

below is the code

```
  <div id="group">
    <div class="col" lines="none">
      <ion-label position="stacked">EXPIRY DATE</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="MM/YY"></ion-input>
    </div>
    <div class="col" lines="none" id="div-security">
      <ion-label position="stacked">SECURITY CODE</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="999"></ion-input>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Inputs with labels that is messing up-->
  <div class="grouping" lines="none">
    <ion-label  display="block">ZIP/POSTAL CODE</ion-label>
    <ion-input placeholder="60001"></ion-input>
  </div>
```

scss

```
    ion-card {

  .col {
    margin-right: 6px;
    float: left;
    width: 171px;

    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px #000;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
  }
  .grouping {
    margin-top: 24px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px #000;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
  }
ion-label {
  height: 18px;
  bottom: 49px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #212121;
}
```

Expected output
[image]

My result
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `Display:inline-block;` to your  grouping class like so:

```
 .grouping {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 24px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px #000;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
  }
```

Worked for me, you can add `width:100%`(or whatever to add the stretch). the Div was defaulting to display block which was causing your issue.